# Como criar uma interface em Python que receba dados, calcule eles e "print" o resultado?

Tags: python, interface

A ideia é o usuário digitar dois valores dentro da interface, apertar um botão para a execução do código e o resultado aparecer na tela. Segue o código abaixo:

```
import requests

from tkinter import *


#Orçamento 3D com Python - Básico

#Dados


MinutosdoProjeto = float(input("Digite os Minutos do Projeto:"))
GramasdoProjeto = int(input("Digite o numero de Gramas do Projeto:"))
ConstanteLuz = float(0.21)
ConstanteLucro = float(4.32)
MaterialGramas = int(1000)
MaterialReais = float(150.00)


#Variaveis

Valor1 = MinutosdoProjeto * ConstanteLuz
Valor2 = MinutosdoProjeto * ConstanteLucro
Valor3 = GramasdoProjeto * MaterialReais / MaterialGramas +0.013
Valor4 = Valor1+Valor2+Valor3


print(" O valor de sua luz é:",Valor1)
print(" O valor de seu lucro é:",Valor2)
print(" O valor de seu Material é:",Valor3)
print(" O valor em Reais é R$:",Valor4)





janela = Tk()
janela.title("Orçamento Impressão 3D")
Entry().grid(row=0, column=0, Text="Minutos do Projeto")
Entry().grid(row=1, column=2, Text="Gramas do Projeto")

Button(text="Fazer o Calculo").grid(row=2, column=0)
janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Faltou explicar qual foi o erro e onde ele ocorre.

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.title("Orçamento Impressão 3D")

def calcular():
    MinutosdoProjeto = float(valor_minutos.get())
    GramasdoProjeto = int(valor_gramas.get())
    ConstanteLuz = float(0.21)
    ConstanteLucro = float(4.32)
    MaterialGramas = int(1000)
    MaterialReais = float(150.00)

    #Cálculos
    Valor1 = MinutosdoProjeto * ConstanteLuz
    Valor2 = MinutosdoProjeto * ConstanteLucro
    Valor3 = GramasdoProjeto * MaterialReais / MaterialGramas + 0.013
    Valor4 = Valor1 + Valor2 + Valor3

    #Imprimir resultado
    resultado.config(text=" O valor de sua luz é: {:.2f}\n O valor de seu lucro é: {:.2f}\n O valor de seu Material é: {:.2f}\n O valor em Reais é R$:{:.2f}".format(Valor1, Valor2, Valor3, Valor4))

# Adicionar as caixas de entrada e o botão
Label(janela, text="Minutos do Projeto").grid(row=0, column=0)
valor_minutos = Entry(janela)
valor_minutos.grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(janela, text="Gramas do Projeto").grid(row=1, column=0)
valor_gramas = Entry(janela)
valor_gramas.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(janela, text="Fazer o Cálculo", command=calcular).grid(row=2, column=0)

# Adicionar o resultado
resultado = Label(janela)
resultado.grid(row=3, column=0)

janela.mainloop()
```

Sobre o código:

'valor_minutos' e 'valor_gramas' são variáveis que armazenam os valores digitados nas caixas de entrada.

A função 'calcular()' é chamada quando o botão "Fazer o Cálculo" é pressionado. Ela utiliza os valores digitados para fazer os cálculos e imprime o resultado na label 'resultado'.

A label 'resultado' é criada vazia e só será preenchida quando o botão for pressionado.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).